# NIFI:How to get node value using variable node name in nifi processor

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

i  have xml  data  like this  below and  i  want to  get  localAttribtes tag  by name 'rs' in my EvaluateXpath  processor  i tried  this expression in my  EvaluateXpath processor `//localAttributes/*[@name='rs']/name()` but  i  don't  get  "rs"  tag  value :
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<service>
<localAttributes name="rs">    
<start>2017-09-07</start>    
<startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>    
<endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>    
<runAs>true</runAs>    
<patch>this is  patch</patch>    
<makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
</localAttributes>
<localAttributes name="ns">    
<start>2017-09-07</start>    
<startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>    
<endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>    
<runAs>true</runAs>    
<patch>this is  patch</patch>    
<makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
</localAttributes>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this case the correct xpath is:

```
//localAttributes[@name='rs']/name()
```

but evaluating `name()` is quite strange because it returns the tag name and you know in advance the tag name - `localAttributes`

if you want to get for example `patch` tag value of `localAttributes` that has attribute `@name` equals to `'rs'`:

```
//localAttributes[@name='rs']/patch
```